# Bug using jqTransform plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tabs, jqtransform

I'm using jqTransform plugin to add some styling in my page's form items.
There are three forms placed in tabs, and the selectboxes in second and third tab are not working correctly.

It seems that for some reason the script applies "height:0" to those selectboxes lists. Here's the code that handles this action:

```
// Calculate the height if necessary, less elements that the default height
//show the ul to calculate the block, if ul is not displayed li height value is 0
$ul.css({display:'block',visibility:'hidden'});
var iSelectHeight = ($('li',$ul).length)*($('li:first',$ul).height());//+1 else bug ff
(iSelectHeight < $ul.height()) && $ul.css({height:iSelectHeight,'overflow':'hidden'});//hidden else bug with ff
$ul.css({display:'none',visibility:'visible'});
```

I really don't understand why is this happening.

Answer (score -1):

Comment out the line

```
(iSelectHeight < $ul.height()) && $ul.css({height:iSelectHeight,'overflow':'hidden'})
```

It works for me.